# Not able to create Information link in Spotfire

Tags: spotfire

I am trying to create an Information link in Spotfire Information designer and keep getting this error. I can access the database and the validated columns as well as database. Any help is really appreciated.

```
`   Error message: Could not open information link.

   TargetInvocationException at Spotfire.Dxp.Framework:
    Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. (HRESULT: 80131604)

Stack Trace:
   at Spotfire.Dxp.Framework.ApplicationModel.ProgressService.ExecuteWithProgress(String title, String description, ProgressOperation operation)
   at Spotfire.Dxp.Forms.Data.InformationDesigner.DesignerFormController.ExecuteInformationLink(CachedInformationLinkElement informationLink)


ImportException at Spotfire.Dxp.Data:
Failed to execute data source query. (HRESULT: 80131500)

Stack Trace:
   at Spotfire.Dxp.Data.DataSourceConnection.ExecuteQuery2()
   at Spotfire.Dxp.Data.DataFlow.Execute()
   at Spotfire.Dxp.Data.DataFlow.DataFlowConnection.ExecuteQueryCore2()
   at Spotfire.Dxp.Data.DataSourceConnection.ExecuteQuery2()
   at Spotfire.Dxp.Data.Producers.SourceColumnProducer.<>c__DisplayClass11.<GetColumnsAndProperties>b__e()
   at Spotfire.Dxp.Framework.ApplicationModel.Progress.ExecuteSubtask(String title, ProgressOperation operation)
   at Spotfire.Dxp.Data.Producers.SourceColumnProducer.GetColumnsAndProperties(DataSourceConnection connection)
   at Spotfire.Dxp.Data.Persistence.DataItem.PerformUpdate(SourceColumnProducer producer, DataSourceConnection connection)
   at Spotfire.Dxp.Data.Persistence.DataItem.Update(SourceColumnProducer producer, DataSourceConnection connection)
   at Spotfire.Dxp.Data.Persistence.DataPool.<LoadData>d__1.MoveNext()
   at Spotfire.Dxp.Data.Producers.SourceColumnProducer.ConfigureAndLoadData()
   at Spotfire.Dxp.Framework.DocumentModel.Node.ConfigureSubTree()
   at Spotfire.Dxp.Framework.DocumentModel.Node.<ConfigureSubTree>b__10(Node node)
   at Spotfire.Dxp.Framework.DocumentModel.Node.ConfigureSubTree()
   at Spotfire.Dxp.Framework.DocumentModel.Node.<ConfigureSubTree>b__10(Node node)
   at Spotfire.Dxp.Framework.DocumentModel.Node.ConfigureSubTree()
   at Spotfire.Dxp.Framework.DocumentModel.Node.<ConfigureSubTree>b__10(Node node)
   at Spotfire.Dxp.Framework.DocumentModel.State.NodeState.ForEachChild(IDocumentNodeChild[] children, Action`1 action)
   at Spotfire.Dxp.Framework.DocumentModel.Node.ConfigureSubTree()
   at Spotfire.Dxp.Framework.ApplicationModel.Progress.ExecuteSubtask(String title, IndeterminateProgressFormatter progressFormatter, ProgressSpeedFormatter speedFormatter, ProgressOperation operation)
   at Spotfire.Dxp.Framework.DocumentModel.DocumentNode.ConfigureAndAttachFromNew()
   at Spotfire.Dxp.Framework.DocumentModel.DocumentNode.AttachSubTreeWhileExecuting(UndoableNode newOwner)
   at Spotfire.Dxp.Framework.DocumentModel.DocumentNode.AttachToUndoableNode(UndoableNode newOwner)
   at Spotfire.Dxp.Framework.DocumentModel.UndoableKeyedCollection`2.<>c__DisplayClass6.<Insert>b__5()
   at Spotfire.Dxp.Framework.DocumentModel.Node.Spotfire.Dxp.Framework.DocumentModel.INode.InternalTransaction(Executor executor)
   at Spotfire.Dxp.Framework.DocumentModel.UndoableKeyedCollection`2.Insert(Int32 index, TNode item)
   at Spotfire.Dxp.Data.DataTableCollection.<>c__DisplayClass11.<Add>b__10()
   at Spotfire.Dxp.Framework.DocumentModel.Node.Spotfire.Dxp.Framework.DocumentModel.INode.InternalTransaction(Executor executor)
   at Spotfire.Dxp.Data.DataTableCollection.Add(String dataTableName, DataSource dataSource, Boolean autoCreateFilters)
   at Spotfire.Dxp.Application.PartiallyOpenedDataSource.<LoadData>d__0.MoveNext()
   at Spotfire.Dxp.Application.AnalysisApplication.<OpenPartiallyOpenedDocument>d__34.MoveNext()
   at Spotfire.Dxp.Application.AnalysisApplication.<OpenDataSource>d__1b.MoveNext()
   at Spotfire.Dxp.Application.AnalysisApplication.ConsumePromptRequests(IEnumerable`1 prompts)
   at Spotfire.Dxp.Application.AnalysisApplication.Open(DataSource source, DocumentOpenSettings settings)
   at Spotfire.Dxp.Forms.Data.Import.DataSourceFactoryService.OpenDataSourceWithoutPrompting(DataSource dataSource, DocumentOpenSettings documentOpenSettings, IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
   at Spotfire.Dxp.Forms.Data.Import.DataSourceFactoryService.OpenDataSource(InformationLinkDataSource dataSource, DocumentOpenSettings documentOpenSettings, IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
   at Spotfire.Dxp.Forms.Data.InformationDesigner.DesignerFormController.<>c__DisplayClass2.<ExecuteInformationLink>b__0()
   at Spotfire.Dxp.Forms.Application.FormsProgressService.ProgressThread.DoOperationLoop()


InformationModelException at Spotfire.Dxp.Data:
An Internal Error has occurred. com.spotfire.ws.dat.OperatorException: unexpected exception (HRESULT: 80131500)

Stack Trace:
   at Spotfire.Dxp.Data.InformationModel.InternalInformationModelManager.DataStream.GetNextBlock()
   at Spotfire.Dxp.Data.InformationModel.InternalInformationModelManager.DataStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at Spotfire.Dxp.Internal.Utilities.SeekableStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at System.IO.BinaryReader.FillBuffer(Int32 numBytes)
   at System.IO.BinaryReader.ReadUInt16()
   at Spotfire.Dxp.Data.Formats.Sbdf.SbdfSectionHeader.ReadSectionType(BinaryReader reader, SbdfSectionTypeId expectedType)
   at Spotfire.Dxp.Data.Import.SbdfDataRowReader.DelayedInit()
   at Spotfire.Dxp.Data.Import.InformationLinkDataSourceConnection.ExecuteQueryCore2()
   at Spotfire.Dxp.Data.DataSourceConnection.ExecuteQuery2()


InformationModelServiceException at Spotfire.Dxp.Services:
An Internal Error has occurred. com.spotfire.ws.dat.OperatorException: unexpected exception (HRESULT: 80131509)

Stack Trace:
   at Spotfire.Dxp.Services.WebServiceBase`1.InvokeService[T](ServiceMethod`1 serviceMethod, ExceptionFactoryMethod exceptionFactoryMethod)
   at Spotfire.Dxp.Data.InformationModel.InternalInformationModelManager.DataStream.GetNextBlock()`
```

Answer (score 2):

Edit the information Link and validate the data types of each column. The most common scenario is a DATE column being set as a LongInteger in Spotfire.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have an access to the database logs as it could be helpful here I think. There is a similar post with resolution based on modification of permissions. Spotfire accessed the db via a user that might not have permissions to db and I am not talking about the db user you provided and verified but more about a .NET user used by Spotfire.

Comment: yes, i can create and pull the data in the same way from different table from same schema but in one it shows this error.

Comment: so it seems you have to investigate the table structure and the data, as permissions doesnt seem to be an issue if it works for different table, but you probaby got the same conclussion - it is more data type issue or a data conversion ...

Comment: the issue is i was able to run the sql query in Oracle without any issues.. not sure why i can't i use the same query...

Comment: as the error code you provided doesnt seem to be enough to answer what is wrong perhaps you could send us the query + the logs from db for moment of attemting to create an information link ?

Comment: THanks All!! I got the error finally- in the data source the fetch size was wrongly set...

Comment: So you might consider marking one of answers as a right one.

Comment: Actually none of above answer was correct, i have mentioned in the comment what the error was.

Answer (score 1):

What version of Spotfire are you running?

If you have access to the Spotfire logs, you should have a server.log and a sql.log.

You should be able to identify the exact query that Spotfire is executing within the sql.log - since it failed it should appear with your user id, information link name and it should be noted as cancelled.

The exact database error should be in the server.log with a timestamp that corresponds to the sql.log cancelled timestamp.